# IContainerBuilder.AddService is not working in IRouteBuilder OData .Net Core in Adding EdmModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

I was using this part of code in OData .Net. This code is working in .Net Core. Here is my configuration class:

```
 public static class Configuration
    {
        public static Action<IApplicationBuilder> ConvertToAppBuilder(Action<object> myActionT)
        {
            if (myActionT == null) return null;
            else return new Action<object>(o => myActionT(o));
        }


        public static Action<IApplicationBuilder> GetBuilder()
        {
            return ConvertToAppBuilder(Configure);
        }

        public static void Configure(object appBuilder)
        {
            var app = appBuilder as IApplicationBuilder;
            var config = new RouteBuilder(app);
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(config.ApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices) { Namespace = "Model.Entities", ContainerName = "DefaultContainer" };

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
            {
                routeBuilder.Select().Filter();
                routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", configureAction: c => c
                .AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Transient, typeof(IEdmModel), sp => GetEdmModel()));
            });
        }

        static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            odataBuilder.EntitySet<Student>("Student");

            return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
```

It is working when I use the first constructor

```
 app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.Select().Filter();
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
        });
```

But I need to use the second constructor because I will add there custom ODataUriResolver. So how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Seams source code has issue on adding custom convension. Following code worked on me:

```
 routeBuilder.MapODataRoute("OData", "odata", b =>
            {
                b.AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => edmModel);
                var customRoutingConvention = new ODataCustomRoutingConvention();
                var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
                //Workaround for https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1622
                conventions.Insert(0, new AttributeRoutingConvention("OData", app.ApplicationServices, new DefaultODataPathHandler()));
                //Custom Convention
                conventions.Insert(0, customRoutingConvention);
                b.AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, a => conventions);
            });
```